# How to resolve Unknown host ({snmp_args}) when using SNMPset while trying to set a store and repeat message on a Kapsch RSU

Tags: snmp

I am SSH'd into the Kapsch RSU with admin credentials and am attempting to manually set a Store and Repeat message on the device.

I am using the SNMP Set command and entered the following parameters. I am unsure what the {snmp_args} portion of the commmand does

```
admin@QZK00608:/home/kapsch$ snmpset {snmp_args} \
> rsuSRMPsid.1 x 8003 \
> rsuSRMDsrcMsgId.1 i 31 \
> rsuSRMTxMode.1 i 0 \
> rsuSRMTxChannel.1 i 176 \
> rsuSRMTxInterval.1 i 1000\
> rsuSRMDeliveryStart.1 x 07e20b071610 \
> rsuSRMDeliveryStop.1 x 07e80b07161a \
> rsuSRMPayload.1 x 07e40b07161a x 001f4d2010000000000266bccdb082b28e6568c461045380342800002fc25445f0e030800200393205a200ba3174a062df5b290f93d901d05dc036e7ec066877d0c34eba16e3d408364010c189408840 \
> rsuSRMEnable.1 i 0 \
> rsuSRMStatus.1 i 4
```

I return the error:

```
Unknown host ({snmp_args})
```

How do I properly set the host?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `snmpset` command is treating `{snmp_args}` as a domain name, and trying to use DNS to resolve it into an IP address. You need to replace `{snmp_args}` with arguments, such as `-v 2c` (assuming you are using version SNMP2c), and either the community string, or the user credentials (if using SNMPv3), followed by the hostname or IP address of the machine you are trying to communicate with. You can find information about these arguments in the `snmpcmd` manual page by typing

```
man snmpcmd
```